# Reproduce gantt chart with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, gantt-chart, ggplotly, vistime

I have made a gantt plot with the vistime library in R and want to reproduce it with plotly.

Here's the result with vistime package

[image]

and the result with plotly

[image]

The problem is the vistime plot there are dots indicating the end of the case but there are not segments in the plotly, plus the text in the segment is not the same.

Code to reproduce

```
# import libraries --------------------------------------------------------

library(readxl) # read xlsx files
library(vistime) # gantt charts
library(plotly) # interactive plots
library(RColorBrewer)

# read and manipulate data ------------------------------------------------


mdat = read_excel('gantt_data.xlsx') ; colnames(mdat)

mdat$start = strptime(mdat$start,
                         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

mdat$complete = strptime(mdat$complete,
                      "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

mdat$start = as.POSIXct(mdat$start,
                           tz ='GMT',
                           format =c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))

mdat$complete = as.POSIXct(mdat$complete,
                           tz ='GMT',
                           format =c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))



# Gantt with vistime ------------------------------------------------------


# Classic palette BuPu, with 4 colors
coul <- brewer.pal(12, "Set3") 
# Add more colors to this palette :
n_labels = length(unique(mdat$ActivityID)); n_labels
coul <- colorRampPalette(coul)(n_labels)

mdat$cols <- factor(mdat$ActivityID, 
                     labels = coul)

vistime(mdat, 
        col.event = 'ActivityID',
        col.group = 'CaseID',
        col.start = 'start',
        col.end = 'complete',
        col.color = 'cols',
        optimize_y = F,
        show_labels = F,
        linewidth = 25
) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE, tickfont=list(size=8),
                    tickangle=-30,
                    showgrid = T),
         title = "Cases with the highest (lead) time",
         plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6"
  )


# Gantt with plotly -------------------------------------------------------

m <- mdat %>%
  mutate(end = coalesce(complete, start)) #works

p <- ggplot(m,
            aes(x=start, xend=end, y=CaseID, yend=CaseID, color=ActivityID, group=CaseID)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")+ #use ggplot theme with black gridlines and white background
  geom_segment(size=8) + #increase line width of segments in the chart
  labs(title='Cases with the highest (lead) time"', x='Time', y='CaseID')


ggplotly(p)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the dataset

https://ufile.io/bk5b8dy1

Comment: As far as I know `vistime()` already outputs a plotly object?

Comment: @ismirsehregal that is correct, I am doing the workaround because I want to use the powerBI service and the version of the vistime package is old.

Comment: Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420179/creating-a-gantt-chart-timeline-in-r-using-only-yyyy-not-dd-mm-yyy/54423737#54423737) to this question